# Div moves down when font-size is smaller than sibling in a flexbox layout

Tags: css, flexbox

On the snippet below I'm using a flexbox layout and I'm noting a weird behaviour that I can't understand.

Please note I'm asking for the **theoretical explanation** of WHY this happens since I already know some workarounds for this.

Problem is on the first header example where I have a container div (a) and then inside 2 inline-block divs (a1, a2). When a2 is set with a font-size smaller than a1 then a2 DIV goes down by some pixels, where I expected both divs to still be aligned and with the same height (given by header line-height). You can see it goes down by the blue top border I added there.

The problem doesn't happen if I remove div 'a' and just move b1 and b2 to be children of the header, as shown in the second header of my example.

I already tried adjusting a few flex properties with no luck (align-items, etc). I also know line-height has some weird tricks that sometimes aren't really obvious but I don't understand WHY this is happening and if this is supposed to be like this or it's a bug.

Tested on Chrome 65, Opera 52 and IE 11 and happens on all.

```css
header {
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
}

.a1, .a2 {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.a2 {
  font-size: 8px;
}

.b1, .b2 {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

.b2 {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="a1">AAAAA1</div>
    <div class="a2">AAAAAAA 2</div>
  </div>
</header>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<header>
    <div class="b1">AAAAA1</div>
    <div class="b2">AAAAAAA 2</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because when using `display: inline-block;` `vertical-align` is set at *baseline* as default.

You can use

```
.a1, .a2 { vertical-align:top; }
```

or

```
.a1, .a2 { display:block; float:left }
```